# Cannot deploy as an msi using javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a problem, whenever I try to deploy my program it gives me an error telling me -

```
Bundler MSI Installer skipped because of a configuration problem: Main
application jar is missing.  
Advice to fix: Make sure to use fx:jar task to create main application jar.
```

although it still completes the build but does not create my msi or exe. I have tried configuring the fx:jar in the build.xml but when run it always comes up with the same error. with the same project on my mac it can deploy as a dmg and pkg no problem it just seems to have a problem with my windows machine. I am almost certain that eclipse is also running on a jdk not a jre. Here is the whole log -

```
Buildfile: E:\Projects\JavaFX\File Utility\build\build.xml
setup-staging-area:
[delete] Deleting directory
E:\Projects\J avaFX\FileUtility\build\externalLibs
[delete] Deleting directory E:\Projects\JavaFX\File Utility\build\project
[delete] Deleting directory E:\Projects\JavaFX\File
Utility\build\projectRefs
[mkdir] Created dir: E:\Projects\JavaFX\File Utility\build\externalLibs
[copy] Copying 1 file to E:\Projects\JavaFX\File Utility\build\externalLibs
[copy] Copying 1 file to E:\Projects\JavaFX\File Utility\build\externalLibs
[mkdir] Created dir: E:\Projects\JavaFX\File Utility\build\project
[copy] Copying 4 files to E:\Projects\JavaFX\File Utility\build\project
[mkdir] Created dir: E:\Projects\JavaFX\File Utility\build\projectRefs
do-compile:
[delete] Deleting directory E:\Projects\JavaFX\File Utility\build\build
[mkdir] Created dir: E:\Projects\JavaFX\File Utility\build\build\src
[mkdir] Created dir: E:\Projects\JavaFX\File Utility\build\build\libs
[mkdir] Created dir: E:\Projects\JavaFX\File Utility\build\build\classes
[copy] Copying 2 files to E:\Projects\JavaFX\File Utility\build\build\libs
[copy] Copying 4 files to E:\Projects\JavaFX\File Utility\build\build\src
[javac] Compiling 3 source files to E:\Projects\JavaFX\File
Utility\build\build\classes
[copy] Copying 1 file to E:\Projects\JavaFX\File Utility\build\build\classes
init-fx-tasks:
do-deploy:
[copy] Copying 2 files to E:\Projects\JavaFX\File Utility\build\dist\libs
[mkdir] Created dir: E:\Projects\JavaFX\File
Utility\build\build\classes\META-INF
Using base JDK at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre
Using base JDK at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre
Bundler MSI Installer skipped because of a configuration problem: Main
application jar is missing.  
Advice to fix: Make sure to use fx:jar task to create main application jar.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 809 milliseconds
```

Build.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="File Utility" default="do-deploy" basedir="."  xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
<target name="init-fx-tasks">
    <path id="fxant">
        <filelist>
            <file name="${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
            <file name="${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
        </filelist>
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
        uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
        classpathref="fxant"/>
</target>
<target name="setup-staging-area">
    <delete dir="externalLibs" />
    <delete dir="project" />
    <delete dir="projectRefs" />

    <mkdir dir="externalLibs" />

    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="C:\Users\Milne\Desktop">
            <filename name="junrar-0.6.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="C:\Users\Milne\Desktop">
            <filename name="zip4j_1.3.2.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="project" />
    <copy todir="project">
        <fileset dir="E:\Projects\JavaFX\File Utility">
            <include name="src/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="projectRefs" />
</target>
<target name='do-compile'>
    <delete dir="build" />
    <mkdir dir="build/src" />
    <mkdir dir="build/libs" />
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />

    <!-- Copy project-libs references -->
    <copy todir="build/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="junrar-0.6.jar"/>
            <include name="zip4j_1.3.2.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <!-- Copy project references -->

    <!-- Copy project sources itself -->
    <copy todir="build/src">
        <fileset dir="project/src">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <javac includeantruntime="false" source="1.8" target="1.8" srcdir="build/src" destdir="build/classes" encoding="Cp1252">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="build/libs">
                <include name="*"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>

    <!-- Copy over none Java-Files -->
    <copy todir="build/classes">
    <fileset dir="project/src">
        <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
    </copy>


</target>
<target name="do-deploy" depends="setup-staging-area, do-compile, init-fx-tasks">
    <delete file="dist"/>
    <delete file="deploy" />

    <mkdir dir="dist" />
    <mkdir dir="dist/libs" />

    <copy todir="dist/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>


    <fx:resources id="appRes">
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="File Utility.jar"/>
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*"/>
    </fx:resources>

    <fx:application id="fxApplication"
        name="File Utility"
        mainClass="application.Main"
        toolkit="fx"
    />

    <mkdir dir="build/classes/META-INF" />



    <fx:jar destfile="build/dist/File Utility.jar">
        <fx:application refid="fxApplication"/>
        <fileset dir="build/classes">
        </fileset>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="Hamish Milne"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="File Utility"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.0"/>
            <attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None"/>
        </manifest>
    </fx:jar>


    <mkdir dir="deploy" />
    <!-- Need to use ${basedir} because somehow the ant task is calculating the directory differently -->
    <fx:deploy
        verbose="true" 
        embedJNLP="false"
        extension="true"
        includeDT="false"
        offlineAllowed="true"
        outdir="${basedir}/deploy"
        outfile="File Utility" nativeBundles="msi"
        updatemode="background" >

        <fx:platform basedir="${java.home}"/>
        <fx:info title="File Utility" vendor="Hamish Milne"/>

        <fx:application refId="fxApplication"/>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
    </fx:deploy>


</target>
```

Comment: Please also post your build.xml, so that we can see how you defined the packaging.

Comment: ok it does it automaticlyy though when I use the build.fxbuild file

Answer (score 1):

```
<fx:resources id="appRes">
    <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="FileUtility.jar"/>
    <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*"/>
</fx:resources>

<fx:jar destfile="build/dist/FileUtility.jar">
    <fx:application refid="fxApplication"/>
        <fileset dir="build/classes">
        </fileset>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes" />

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="Hamish Milne"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="File Utility" />
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="application.Main" />
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.0" />
            <attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${classpath.string}" />
        </manifest>
    </fx:jar>
```

Set your classpath as well to include any dependencies.

Modify your build xml.

Comment: I don't think its a problem with finding the main class as it says in the log its unable to locate the jar file itself but honestly I don't know.

Comment: Mistake on my part, keep the jar file as on string. Change "File Utility.jar" to "FileUtility.jar"

Comment: Yeah ok ill try that once i get home.